# Display a certain page in a view

Tags: 7, views

Here is what I'm trying to do is display a certain page in a view instead of all of the basic pages.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Add contextual filter `Nid`. Select provide default value and then select fixed value and type in the node id #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change what is shown on the site front page you can do that under Configure > System > Site information.

Enter `node/[number]` into the **Default front page** field (replace the [number] with the node ID of the content you want to appear on the front page).

---

If you want to change Content Views to show only a particular node add the Filter `Content: Nid` with the **Operator** set to `Is equal to` and enter your node ID number in the **Value** field.

This will show only the one node information on that Views.